# How to nullify keys simulation for special characters in TestComplete tool?

Tags: javascript, sendkeys, testcomplete

Can anyone tell me how to nullify the simulation for special characters in TestComplete?

I am trying to send a password to the `runas` window like:

```
hCmd.Keys(a_Password + "[Enter]")
```

where `hCmd` is the handle for the `runas` command window.

But if the password value contains any special characters like `!` or `^`, TestComplete is simulating the keys to Shift or Ctrl etc..

Is there a way to nullify such operation by TestComplete for a specified part in the keys like a HTML tag before and after the password so that all characters will be typed as it is between these tags?

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape these special characters by doubling them:

`!` → `!!`

`~` → `~~`

`^` → `^^`

`[` → `[[`

This is actually mentioned in the key code table in the [documentation](http://smartbear.com/support/viewarticle/11324/).

If you are retrieving the `a_Password` value from an external source, then simply do a string replace before passing it to the `Keys` method. For example:

```
a_Password = a_Password.replace("!", "!!").replace("~", "~~").replace("^", "^^").replace("[", "[[");
// or
a_Password = a_Password.replace(/[!~^[]/g, "$&$&");
```

> Just curious to know if there any solution provided by Testcomplete for such scenarios?

String replace is only solution I'm aware of, and is a pretty simple one. Note also that this is only needed when you "type" text using `Keys`. When you set the text programmatically using `wText` or similar properties, there's no need to escape those special characters or otherwise preprocess the text.

Comment: Helen, but the problem is I am passing the parameter a_Password from outside where I do not want to declare it with the escape characters. Also it looks awkward to have a variable value declared keeping the escape characters and sometimes misleading too